# Keep getting Exec format error while trying mono-4.2.2 for Windows

Tags: .net, windows, mono

I've just downloaded and installed mono-4.2.2.30 for Windows on my Windows XP SP3 Laptop (The installation file name: *mono-4.2.2.30-gtksharp-2.12.30-win32-0.msi*)
It installed itself into **C:\Program Files\Mono** directory. 
I've defined the Mono's bin folder in my **~/.bashrc**

When I run any command such as **mcs** or **mono** from Mono bin directory it always gives this error:

```
sh: /c/Program Files/Mono/bin/mono: binary file cannot be executed: Exec format error
```

It gives this error on the **ConEmu** terminal emulator using **MSYS** but if I try it on other shells such as **cmd.exe** or **git bash** the same or similar error comes up.

The reason I want to use Mono for Windows is because I'd like to use .NET 4.6 apps on my Windows XP Laptop. I have installed Mono on my Mac OSX, too and I have successfully run .NET apps on it.

Inspecting the Mono commands by **ldd** gives the same error in short form: **"Exec format error"** However, inspecting the same commands by **file** returns:

```
$ file /c/Program\ Files/Mono/bin/mcs
/c/Program Files/Mono/bin/mcs: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
$ file /c/Program\ Files/Mono/bin/mono
/c/Program Files/Mono/bin/mono: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mono is not compatible with WindowsXP.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Basically Mono is compatible with WinXP. However, it's been said that since the Mono version 3.2.3 it became incompatible. Strange that there are no remarks about this on the Mono download page. Even stranger is that while even .NET 4.5 is technically compatible with WinXP the corresponding Mono versions are incompatible.